# How do I iteratively call sqldf on a vector of strings? (naming list elements in R)

Tags: r, list, sqldf

My goal is to create a list with each element containing a dataframe.
The dataframes are created by calling `sqldf` iteratively.

An example of what I want to do is this:
I have a vector `names` containing the names of my list.

```
> names
[1] "hello" "world"`
```

The list is called `L`, and is of length `length(names)`.
Right now, `L` looks like this

```
> L
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 0
```

I want it to look like:

```
> L
$hello
  Year Total
1 2000   100
2 2001   200

$world
  Year Total
1 2000   150
2 2001   250
```

The first element `L$hello` is created by calling

```r
names(L)[1] <- "hello"

L$hello <- sqldf(select Year, sum(case when names='hello' then Nums) as Total from Data group by Year")
```

Similarly, the second element `L$world` is created by replacing "'hello'" in that function call with "'world'".

However, this is a big problem if I have a lot of names.

My attempt to iterate this is here:

```
for (i in names) {

    j=j+1
    names(L)[j] <- i
    L[[j]] <- sqldf("select Year, sum(case when names='names[names == i]' then Nums end) as 'Total' from Data group by Year")

}
```

The problem is definitely in the third line in the `for` loop where I have the `names='names[names == i]'` argument. How would I amend this?

I think it boils down to: How do I "paste" a string into a function call?

e.g. Instead of doing:

```
sqldf("select Year, sum(case when names='hello' then Nums end) as 'Total' from Data group by Year")
```

if I have a variable `x` where `x <- "hello"`, how would I "paste" `x` into the `sqldf` function?

Answer (score 1):

The sqldf package automatically loads the gsubfn package which provides `fn$` for string interpolation.  Preface `sqldf` with `fn$` and then in the SQL string use

1. $ for a straight substitution or
2. backquotes to execute the code between the backquotes replacing all that with the output of the code.

Note that `fn$`  is a general facility that can preface just about any function to pre-process its arguments -- it is not specific to sqldf.

Here are some examples. Note that `BOD` and `iris` are built into R.

```
library(sqldf)

a <- 3
fn$sqldf("select * from BOD where Time > $a")
##   Time demand
## 1    4   16.0
## 2    5   15.6
## 3    7   19.8

fn$sqldf("select * from BOD where Time > `a+1`")
##   Time demand
## 1    5   15.6
## 2    7   19.8

irisType <- "setosa"
fn$sqldf("select sum([Petal.Length]) from iris where Species = '$irisType'")
##   sum([Petal.Length])
## 1                73.1
```

If you want to see the final string that is passed to `sqldf` add the argument `verbose = TRUE` to the `sqldf` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glue` and `map` over your names vector

```
library(sqldf)
library(glue)
library(purrr)

map(setNames(my.names, my.names), ~
    "select sum(case when a = '{.x}' then b end) as Total 
     from df" %>% 
      glue %>% 
      sqldf)

# $`hello`
#   Total
# 1    24
# 
# $world
#   Total
# 1    31
```

You can do this without `glue` or `purrr` but to my eye it looks a little uglier

```
lapply(setNames(my.names, my.names), function(x)
  sqldf(paste0("select sum(case when a = '", x, "' then b end) as Total 
                from df")))
# $`hello`
#   Total
# 1    24
# 
# $world
#   Total
# 1    31
```

**Example data used in this answer:**

```
my.names <- c("hello", "world")
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(my.names, 10, T), b = sample(1:10))
```